# Having problem running CAN in STM32 with Proteus

Tags: embedded, stm32, can-bus, proteus

I'm trying to run a very basic CAN protocol project with STM32f103 in proteus using STM32CubeIde. i know proteus doesn't fully support can bus and also i need to use a can transceiver but this is a very basic project just to send and receive data between 2 stm32. the problem i'm having, the stm32 stop working.
i use a blink led as an indicator, when i remove the CAN interface, the led is blinking, but when i add the CAN interface, nothing happen.

i used UART for debugging, and i can see that the program stuck (doesn't return anything) in the can init function `HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan)` and precisely in `SET_BIT(hcan->Instance->MCR, 0x1UL);` in the stm32f1xx_hal_can.c file, i tried to remove that line but it's stuck again in `while ((hcan->Instance->MSR & CAN_MSR_INAK) == 0U)`, not inside the while but in `(hcan->Instance->MSR & CAN_MSR_INAK)`, so i'm not sure if i'm missing something in the configuration or it's from the proteus. by the way, i just did the configuration and no interruption was involved and i just tried to run the generated program.

[image]

Comment: Instead of relying on all these tools and libraries, you'll have to actually read the friendly manual and find out _why_ it is stuck. Aimlessly commenting out random lines inside libraries is not how to troubleshoot software.

Comment: it's not random lines, it calls "bug localization", and to make sure it's that line and not a random problem (like period of time passed) causes the problem, we do such thing to be 100% sure that's where the problem come from, and since it's a simple macro that changes a bit in register, that problem is so weird and specially i didn't even wrote a single line in the new project (all i did, stm32 configuration inside the cube MX), and i followed many tutorials and they did the same thing, so i left with 2 options, am i missing something or this is a proteus problem and i need to use a real stm